# How to force HashMap to use identity (hash code)? or suggest workaround

Tags: java, hashmap, equality, mutable

Earlier I have coded HashMap to store some objects, which was expecting to use identity while storing them. I.e. objects were treated "same" if `Object.equals()` was saying this.

Later I coded `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for classes of these objects with content evaluating paradigm. Immediately my previous `HashMap` stopped to work, because objects were mutating and becoming unequal.

How to plug some simple workaround, to make earlier code to work? May be there is a way to force `HashMap` to use identity despite the fact there are `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods defined?

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer:

Use an [`IdentityHashmap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html).

Long answer:

It is **extremely bad practice** to have `equals` and `hashCode` on mutable properties. It in fact makes sense that the `Map` stopped working if you think of this logically.

Imagine I have `ColourWrapper` class:

```
class ColourWrapper {

    private Color color;

    //getter/setter omitted

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 83 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.color);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final ColourWrapper other = (ColourWrapper) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.color, other.color)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now I put a `ColourWrapper wrapper` wrapping `Color.RED` into my `Map`. I later change the colour of this wrapper to `Color.GREEN`. Now I want to get the value mapped to `wrapper`, what would I do?

In fact **I cannot**. The `Map` has already allocated the `wrapper` to a bucket that corresponds to its hashcode (`-65287`), now I mutate the wrapped `Color` to green and the hash code changes.

The `Map` certainly isn't told about this, so when the hash code changes its bucket does not. It is now "lost".

If you plan to use a `class` as a key in a `Map` then it **should be immutable**. In order to change a mapping:

1. Remove the previous mapping
2. Create a new key
3. Put the new mapping into the map

Comment: Thanks. Then how to compare mutable objects?

Comment: @Dims `equals` and `hashCode` are JDK classes inherited from `Object` and should not be used for this purpose. Add your own method that does what you want.

Comment: *"It is extremely bad practice to have equals and hashCode on mutable properties."* I don't agree with this. There are numerous examples of mutable classes with equals and hashCode. Rather, they are just not appropriate as keys in a HashMap.

Comment: @Radiodef I disagree. Whist you are correct that it is fine if the object is never used a key in a `Map` it is very hard to make that guarantee. Someone will one day use it as a key in a map and then the sun will explode...

Comment: @BoristheSpider why do library arrays and lists, like `ArrayList` implement both `equals` and `hashCode` then?